# Align checkbox and label

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a form which code looks like this:

```
<div id="right_sidebar">

<form id="your_name" name="your_name" action="#" method="post" style="display: block; "> 
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
                <label for="msg"><a href="#" rel="nofollow" id="msg_toggle">Comment <span class="sp"></span></a></label>
        <textarea name="msg" id="msg" rows="7"></textarea>
        <input type="checkbox" name="agree">
        <label for="agree">Accept the terms</label>
                <button class="blue_button" type="submit">Send</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>​
```

And which is styled with the following CSS:

```
body {
color: #333;
font: 12px Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

#right_sidebar {
padding-top: 12px;
width: 190px;
position:relative;
}

form {
background: #EEF4F7;
border: solid red;
border-width: 1px 0;
display: block;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 10px;
}

form label {
color: #435E66;
    display:block;
font-size: 12px;
    }

form textarea {
border: 1px solid #ABBBBE;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 4px 3px;
width: 160px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
form label a {
display: block;
padding-left: 10px;
position: relative;
text-decoration: underline;
}


form label a .sp {
background: #EEF4F7;
height: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
width: 0;
border-top: 4px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
border-left: 4px solid #333;
}

form button.blue_button {
margin-top: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
}

button.blue_button{
color: white;
font-size: 12px;
height: 22px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
button.blue_button {
background-color: #76C8C6;
border: 1px solid #7798B7;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #567C9E;
}
```

​As you can see the checkbox is on top of the label. I would like both to be "on the same line". So, it would look like "[ ] Accept the terms". And how would I make that the text is vertically aligned to the checkbox.

How could I do both?

You can see it live here: [form, checkbox failing](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwmkk/)

Comment: Please remove anything you can without making the problem disappear. It will make the problem a lot easier to solve for us and who knows, you might find out what the problem is yourself in the process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to amend the style of the `label` element that follows the checkbox:

```
​input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nwmkk/9/).

This is, however, somewhat fragile as the `margin`s are a little arbitrary (and the `margin-right` is purely to force the following `button` to the next line). Also the attribute-equals selector may cause problems in older browsers.

As implied, in comments, by Mr. Alien it is actually easier to target the checkbox itself with this selector-notation:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.4em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nwmkk/10/).

Comment: in this case even this is enough I guess `​input[type=checkbox] { /* Styles */ }`

Comment: It depends on the element to be styled, really. I chose to target the `label` rather than the checkbox but, yes, it's equally valid (and possibly easier) to style the checkbox itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the label has `display: block` on it. It means that (without a float or hack) it will claim it's own line.
Change it to `display: inline-block` or leave the display rule away and you're done.

Seeing you did this intentionally for the first two labels, you should give the `accept the terms` label an id and use `form #accepttermslabel {display: inline-block}`. This will override the other rules et because it is more specific.

Comment: If I do this, then the Send button goes on the right of the label... As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/CRg93/

Comment: Then do `display: block` for the send button. @HommerSmith

Comment: Ok...Why did you choose inline-block instead of inline?

Comment: `inline-block` allows for the element to have a defined `width` or `height`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your checkbox and text within the `<label>` tag. Works with your current CSS as seen here in this [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Scnn/).

```
<label for="checkbox">
    ​<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"> My Label
</label>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: I don't think that is for what labels are meant.

Comment: This is the way I've always markedup checkboxes and radio elements...I've seen it used this way many times. He asked for a way to align it horizontally. This solves his answer.

Comment: Then explain to me what the `attribute` is for.

Comment: if you don't know what attributes are for then why are you commenting on my non-semantically correct ways? :P

Comment: It's a perfectly fine and valid HTML5 notation. You can even omit the `for`attribute. However, it doesn't really solve the issue in question (alignment).

Answer (score 0):

Forked your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Astraldiva/sBRcn/1/) with one small change. I nested the checkbox inside the label.

```
    <label for="agree"><input type="checkbox" name="agree">Accept the terms</label>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just ran the validator on it and it was valid.

Comment: It may be valid, but that does not mean it is semantically appropriate. It simply means there are no errors.

Comment: Where could one check and learn if it is semantically appropriate?

Comment: Both the W3's and WHATWG's HTML5 specs explicitly state that you can specify the target of a label by putting it inside a label. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-label-element and http://developers.whatwg.org/forms.html#the-label-element (although you don't use `for` when you do it that way).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add `display: inline` to the `label`. Like this:

```
label[for="agree"] {
  display: inline;
}
```

You may also have to add the following to get the `Send` button to stay on its own line:

```
button[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
}
```

That is enough to make it work, but you could also nest the `input` inside the `label`, like this:

```
<label for="agree">
  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" />
  Accept the terms
</label>
```

However, most people avoid doing this because it is semantically constricting. I would go with the first method.

Comment: you yourself said agree and you are placing the input checkbox in the label element

Comment: @RandomGuy I said it is possible, but if you read the bottom sentence, I say it is semantically improper.

Comment: Jon, thanks for your answer. I like this of putting it inline, but that makes that the "Send" button goes inline too. So it ends up like this http://jsfiddle.net/CRg93/ -- Also, why inline and not inline-block?

Comment: I prefer to use `inline` instead of `inline-block` for semantics. `inline-block` is meant when you want to have block-element styles on an inline element, which is not necessary in this case. But if you do want block-element styles (such as width, height, etc.) then you should use `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Set a class on the checkbox list as follows:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkProject" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns="3" CssClass="FilterCheck"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Then add the following CSS:

```
.FilterCheck td {
    white-space:nowrap !important;
}
```

This ensures the label stays on the same line as the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with bootstrap 3 horizontal-form, and finally found a try-error solution and works with plain html-css too.
Check my [Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alvk4r/bpjw0h5f/)

```css
.remember {
    display: inline-block;
}
.remember input {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label class="remember" for="remember_check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_check" /> Remember me
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried the [flex attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)?
Here's [your example with flex](https://jsfiddle.net/Nwmkk/371/) added:

1. HTML

   ```
   <div id="right_sidebar">
   <form id="send_friend" name="send_friend" action="#" method="post" style="display: block; ">
   <fieldset>
       <label for="from">From</label>
       <input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="">
       <label for="to">To</label>
       <input type="text" name="to" id="to">
       <label for="msg"><a href="#" rel="nofollow" id="msg_toggle">Comment <span class="sp"></span></a>
       </label>
       <textarea name="msg" id="msg" rows="7"></textarea>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="cell" float="left">
               <input type="checkbox" name="agree">
           </div>
           <div class="cell" float="right" text-align="left">
               <label for="agree">Accept the terms</label>
           </div>
       </div>
       <button class="blue_button" type="submit">Send</button>
   </fieldset>
   </form>
   </div>
   ```
2. CSS

   ```
   body {
       color: #333;
       font: 12px Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   [class="row"] {
       display: flex;
       flex-flow: row wrap;
       margin: 2 auto;
   }
   [class="cell"] {
       padding: 0 2px;
   }
   #right_sidebar {
       padding-top: 12px;
       width: 190px;
       position:relative;
   }
   form {
       background: #EEF4F7;
       border: solid red;
       border-width: 1px 0;
       display: block;
       margin-top: 10px;
       padding: 10px;
   }
   form label {
       color: #435E66;
       display:block;
       font-size: 12px;
   }
   form textarea {
       border: 1px solid #ABBBBE;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
       padding: 4px 3px;
       width: 160px;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px;
       border-radius: 3px;
   }
   form label a {
       display: block;
       padding-left: 10px;
       position: relative;
       text-decoration: underline;
   }
   form label a .sp {
       background: #EEF4F7;
       height: 0;
       left: 0;
       position: absolute;
       top: 2px;
       width: 0;
       border-top: 4px solid transparent;
       border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
       border-left: 4px solid #333;
   }
   form button.blue_button {
       margin-top: 10px;
       vertical-align: top;
   }
   button.blue_button {
       color: white;
       font-size: 12px;
       height: 22px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px;
       border-radius: 3px;
   }
   button.blue_button {
       background-color: #76C8C6;
       border: 1px solid #7798B7;
       text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #567C9E;
   }
   ```

Flex allows for table style control with the use of divs for example.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found to have the checkbox and the label aligned is :

```css
    .aligned {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
        <label for="check">
            <input class="aligned" type="checkbox" id="check" /> align me 
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="aligned" type="checkbox" />
        <label>align me too</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>dont align me</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is old, but I'd like to help those who will see this in the future. The answer is pretty simple.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="accept_terms_and_conditions" value="true" />
<label id="margin-bottom:8px;vertical-align:middle;">I Agree</label>
```