# ASP.NET MVC: Align checkbox and label on same line

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

The label ("Acid-stable amino acids") and checkbox are on different lines in my ASP.NET Core MVC application. (Sample ID is irrelevant here.) I would like them to be on the same line. Current misaligned output:

[image: misaligned checkbox]

The field from the model:

```
[Display(Name = "Acid-stable amino acids")]
        public bool AcidStables { get; set; }
```

The Razor view (removing most other irrelevant elements):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form asp-action="Create">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ClientSampleID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ClientSampleID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ClientSampleID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label asp-for="AcidStables" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="AcidStables" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="AcidStables" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried a few things recommended in similar questions. Using inline-block display right before the label:

```
<div class="checkbox">
                <style type="text/css">
                    label {
                        display: inline-block;
                    }

                </style>
```

Or modifying the label or checkbox types in the site.css file:

```
.label {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 5px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.4em;
}
```

or

```
​input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

I've tried changing  to "form-horizontal".

Nothing changes the alignment of checkbox and label. Any input would be appreciated. Floating the checkbox may be a solution but I'm not sure how to do that. Relevant SO questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716968/put-checkbox-and-label-on-the-same-line-mvc), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166501/asp-net-checkbox-cant-get-label-on-same-line-as-checkbox), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212737/align-checkbox-and-label).

edit: rendered HTML--
[image: rendered html]

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: In the _Layout.cshtml file, https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: can you post code about `input[type=checkbox]`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: in your code that you posted I can not see any input with `type="checkbox"`

Comment: Sorry, I've been using <div class="checkbox"> instead of  <div class="form-group">. Will edit OP.

Comment: do your input has `type="checkbox"`?

Comment: Do you mean the following? Just tried this, no difference: <input asp-for="AcidStables" class="form-control" type="checkbox"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192612/discussion-between-heds1-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply `css` like

```
.checkbox .control-label{
   float:left;
   width:40%;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{
   float:left;
   width:60%;
}
.checkbox:after{
   content:'';
   display:block;
   clear:both;
}
```

Comment: @לבנימלכה yes of course, but there is not any bootstrap 4 class in inspector image so we can apply float to it.

Comment: No change unfortunately; even making "float:right" makes no difference.

Comment: @heds1 ok, Is css applying which you are adding?

Comment: Your comment pointed me in the right direction :) Turns out my browser was using the cached site.css file, so I had to clear cache and restart the browser, and that fixed it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From Bootstrap v4.0 and higher you can use:

```
<div class="form-group form-check">
    <label asp-for="AcidStables" class="form-check-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="AcidStables" class="form-check-input"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="AcidStables" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

This is a cleaner solution if you're already using Bootstrap, because you don't need to write additional CSS.

Note: The 'form-group' class is optional, but it gives nicer spacing if used in a form.